# A machine has $9$ switches. Each switch has $3$ positions. How many different settings are possible?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A machine has $9$ switches. Each switch has $3$ positions.

$(1)$ How many different settings are possible?

Each switch has $3$ different settings and we have $9$ total. So,

$3^9=19,683$

Now, the problem I am facing is what the heck the second part is asking.

$(2)$ Answer $(1)$ if each position is used $3$ times. How would you interpret this? I see it as; if we have a certain position for the $9$ switches, say, ABCABCABC then that position is accounted for $2$ additional times $(3$ times total$)$. Thus, we would multiply part $(1)$ by $3$ because we are simply tripling our possibilities?

Any ideas on how part $(2)$ should be approached would be great!

Comment: For the first part, there are no combinations involved. It is simply $3^9$ (which happens to be the same, but there is no reason to use combinations). For the second part, I think they mean that position 1 occurs in some three of the nine switches, position 2 is also used in exactly three places, and ditto for position 3; so 112213233 is allowed, but 111122311 is not. This will be a little tougher to count.

Comment: I think it's just (9 choose 3) to pick the A switches, times (6 choose 3) to pick the B switches. The rest are the C switches.

Comment: Thanks for all the input everyone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint for 2**: How many different words can you spell with the letters AAABBBCCC?

Comment: $9!$/($3!3!3!$)

Comment: ...using all of the letters, of course. Words like "CAB" are not permitted.

Comment: @MPW Yes, true! In probabilistic combinatorics this is typically understood; "word" should be interpreted as "distinguishable letter arrangements" using all the letters given.

Comment: @VincentValentine Yup!

Comment: That's the clarification I was prompting for. I knew what you meant, just being intentionally obtuse ;) Your hint is quite nice, actually. It couches the problem in a form that somehow seems much more tractable, at least to me. +1 for that!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (2) is supposed to be less than the answer to (1), because instead being free to pick any of the 3 positions for each of the 9 switches, you can only pick combinations that have three switches in the A position, three in the B position, and three in the C position. So ABCABCABC works, AAABBBCCC works, but AAAAABBCC is not an option.

Comment: That is likely the appropriate way to interpret it.

Comment: What about multiplying by $3!$ for each of the $3$ A, $3$ B, and $3$ C? Or, must be ignore this because the switches would already have a specific orientation on the machine and thus we don't need to account for different orientations of 3 A, 3 B, 3 C?

Answer (score 1):

Select one of the three positions. How many ways can you choose 3 of the 9 switches with that position? After that, how many ways can you choose 3 of the 6 switches in one of the two different remaining switches? Finally, how many ways can you choose the remaining 3 switches for the last position?

What are the total number of possibilities?

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is very simple. Position as was noted by MPW is just value 1,2,3 for a switch. So in (2) we have all combinations of 3 ones,twos, and thirds. The answer is just $9!/6^3$ because  the first 1 can be set on 9 position, the second on 8, etc. After this since we count any 3 same digits 6 times we have to divide it by 6^3.  This is how I see the picture,
So IMHO answer is $9!/6^3=1680$.

Answer (score 1):

You're off to a good start.

If each position is used exactly three times you do indeed wish to count the permutations of a string such as “`AAABBBCCC`”.  This is the multiset permutation: $$\dbinom{9}{3, 3, 3}=\dfrac{9!}{3!3!3!}$$

There are $9!$ ways to arrange $9$ symbols.  However, many of these will be equivalent, because the order of identical symbols is not important.  There are $3!$ equivalent ways to arrange three identical symbols.  Thus there are $\frac{9!}{3!3!3!}$ distinct ways to arrange $3$ groups of $3$ kinds of symbols.